# IndexError: list index out of range with different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

I am not quite sure what it is I am doing wrong with my code to get this error. I've been looking around to see if I could find somebody having the same problem but I have had no success thus far. The code is:

```
def sort(dislis):
    for index in range(0,len(lst)):
        currval= dislis[index]
        position = index
        while position>0 and dislis[position-1]>currval:
                                 dislis[position] = dislis[position-1]
                                 position = position-1
                                 dislis[position]=currval
```

The traceback error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:", line 49, in <module>
distance()
File "", line 47, in distance
sort(dislis)
File "", line 20, in sort
currval= dislis[index]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: elcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You leave us to hand-enter the test case each time, and you've shown no error message, no tracing attempt.

Comment: please provide the full traceback of the error

Comment: Can we get a exact error(traceback)? And can you limit the code you send to that relating to said traceback? Thats a large amount of code for what seems to be a small problem and because of this its hard to really point out what the issue is quickly. Id recommend running the program, getting a exact traceback, and then edit your question to limit the amount of code we actually need.

Comment: @NaruS I'll do that now.

Comment: Do you think this is better @Prune I'm still new to this so I'm working on getting better at asking questions still

Comment: @NaruS I changed it to 0 but the error stayed the same

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide a copy of the error verbatim(word for word) If possible, format it as if it were code @Makk

Comment: I see the error is related to the line caused by `currval= dislis[index]` thanks for getting it, can you please identify the value index? I see it, but its not show when defined, the addition of this line would be great!

Comment: @NaruS All the things I have for the changing of the index are present and the thing I'm going through is a set of sublists in a list made via user input

Comment: Your current code doesn't run: there's no calling program.  Also, the error message currently in your question is unrelated to the posted code.

Comment: @Prune I put in the wrong error which was my bad and the section of code I gave is the section pertaining to my question so people can more easily identify my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def sort(dislis):
    for index in range(0,len(dislis)):
        currval= dislis[index]
        position = index
        while position>0 and dislis[position-1]>currval:
            dislis[position] = dislis[position-1]
            position = position-1
            dislis[position]=currval

    return dislis

result = sort([3,4,2,1])

print(result)
```

A few little bugs in there preventing it from running, try this out instead.

Also, I highly recommend using only spaces, and not tabs at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand where I went wrong and thanks for the advice!